# Using [email] instead of [gmail], [hotmail], etc

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it worth having individual email provider tags ([gmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail), [hotmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail), etc...) Or should we encourage that these just fall under [mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail)?

I know there could be some instances where they would be helpful, but would it be better to separate them into a provider/service pair?

For instance, instead tagging a question [yahoomail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoomail) would it be more worthwhile to tag it [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[email](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)? This would also let you do things like [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[calendar](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) or even [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[contacts](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts)

The same could be done with [google](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google), [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live), [exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange), and the other built in providers on the phone.

What are your thoughts? I'm not necessarily pushing for this, but I thought it might make a better way to organize the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Watch out with that.*

It doesn't feel right to host [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) or [hotmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) together with [gmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) under [mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail). Because [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) or [hotmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) is closer to Microsoft and might  allow more things to be done than the other, especially with regards to things like the Marketplace, SkyDrive and what else requires a Live ID.

The same goes for [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) vs [exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange), the mail client on the Windows Phone functions quite different between both. For instance, I can't flag my mails on [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) while my father can do that on his [exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) account. Also, [exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchange) isn't using IMAP like [windows-live](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) does; which could bring other differences along as well.

I also think that [google](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) shouldn't be synonymous to [gmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail), because you could ask questions about something like Google Docs on the Windows Phone or perhaps Google itself. This could be resolved by retagging [google](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) questions to one of [gmail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)/[gdocs](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdocs)/[google-search](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search).

As for Yahoo, I would go for more specific tags ([yahoo-mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail)/[yahoo-calender](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-calender)/...) such that they are consistent with how Google tags are used. I'm not quite sure though, but we need to consider:

1. Is the [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) tag useful for searching? Who would search all [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) questions?
2. Is littering the [mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail)/[calendar](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)/... tags with Yahoo questions OK?
3. Do we want to make it harder to search for [yahoo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) or easier using [yahoo-mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail)?

These three questions could also be useful for deciding how to tag the other questions; to summary these questions think about categorization, search-ability and what the tags contribute to the question.

So, when we plan to retag any of the above, we need to be careful with how we approach it.